# How to convert the 0..* to 2 cardinality into a relational model?

Tags: mysql, uml

How do I express the below classes (A and B) in relational model?

[image]

Comment: Can you give a bit of background?  I'm not clear on why you have a two and only two multiplicity.  Relational model works on the one-to-many principle, so I suspect that your model could be a bit off.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could create table A with two required (not null) foreign keys to B. You might want to add a table constraint to prevent the same instance being referenced twice.

A more general approach is to use a "link table" between A and B, and add a constraint on the link table to make sure each instance of A has a link two different instances of B (I guess that would be a rather complex constraint). You could also opt to validate the constraint in your business logic layer rather then your in your database.

Comment: I'm not sure that the model is satisfied by using two foreign keys to B, Geert.  The OP is saying that two and only two instances of B are associated with zero to many instances of A, isn't he?  I'm still not clear on either why or how.  I would model your solution (I think) using two associations and key notation.